# /usr/lib taking 4GB of space

Tags: storage

I recently installed Ubuntu for the first time and switched the desktop environment from gnome to kde to avoid scaling resolution issues and /usr/lib is already taking 4.6GB of space most of which comes from x86_64-linux-gnu folder,and the modules and firmware folder. Are these numbers normal ?

[image]

Comment: seems normal to me

Comment: Question title: `usr/home`, question body: `/usr/lib`. Please fix the title of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, do not worry. This is the normal range for the `/usr/lib` directory. It contains binary libraries of all your excutables in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin`, so that counts up in the proportion of the system disk space it occupies.

Comment: Thanks for the help